# Linux: How to delete all of the files (not directories) inside a directory itself (not childs)

Tags: linux, file, find, xargs, rm

There are some files in a directory whose names is not usual (E.g. in unicode format).
How to delete them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, find the files and then delete them:

```
find [dir_path] -maxdepth 1 -type f  | xargs rm -rf
```

Above is simple and not works when there is a space in any of file name(s). So, I've written a complex and complete command to handle spaces also:

```
find ./ -maxdepth 1 -type f  | awk -F '/' '{printf "'\''%s'\''\n",$2}' | xargs rm -rf
```

"***-maxdepth 1***" means just from the directory not childs. In the other means, not recursive find. As you know, "***xargs***" executes a following command on the list sent to it.

Comment: this helped me a lot , yes its not working with the filenames with spaces. still thanks it saves lot time of mine.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the `rm`:

```
rm .* *
```

It doesn't delete directories and doesn't recurse into them by default.